# Modify existing excel file with macro using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, angular, frontend

I am now working on an Angular application that modifies an existing excel file (.xls) uploaded by the user then save the modified file in the local. The point is this excel file contains some fancy styling and a lot of macros, with several buttons which contains a lot of VBA code (I am not excel expert, sorry if I mistake their name).
I have tried several existing solutions till now:

- [xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)
- [exceljs](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs)

For the first solution, I can only access the community version which basically ignores all these information: style, macro/VBA.

For the second solution, it can preserve almost every style but ignores the macro/VBA.

Except for these solutions, I haven't found any working solution. I turn to the community for help, any kind of solution, even a little hint would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm in the middle of a similar mess, and as far as I can tell, your best bet is to 1. unpack the file (xlsx is a zip) 2. do some changes to the relevant xml documents based on the [reference](http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML-xlsx.php) 3. zip it back up

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! I never thought about this !!! It would be a little bit complicated when applying to my situation but I will have a try.

Comment: Less complicated than your current approach, I guess? ;)